# Custom ListBox with LiveBindings

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, livebindings

I'm trying to make a custom ListBox that has more details and a link with LiveBindings. 
In bindlist I only see the standard fields: Text, Detail, Bitmap....

When trying to bind in the following code:

```
  Item := bliMS.FillExpressions.AddExpression;
  Item.ControlMemberName := 'SubTitle';
  Item.SourceMemberName := 'PAY_NAME';
```

An exception is raised:

> Project xxxxxx raised exception class EEvaluatorError with message 'Couldn't find SubTitle'.

How can I add the SubTitle name to my custom ListBox?

Comment: Is your custom ListBox an object or a Class? I'd expect you would need to create a TMyListBox custom component, with a published SubTitle property and register.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement:  `Item.ControlMemberName := 'SubTitle';`  won't work because there is no actual **ControlMember** / object / "field" in the ListBox/`TList<ListViewItem>` (actually, it's more correct to say that there is none in each of the `ListBoxItem` objects in the the `Items` **TList** actually) called 'SubTitle'.

***Instead*** you have to use on of the *built-in* **text** objects (**ControlMembers**), of which, there are only 2:

1. `Item.Text`
2. `Item.Detail`

If you for some reason have to have a '`SubTitle`' **ControlMember**, then you would need to create a custom `ListBox` or **`ListBoxItemAppearance`** object and register it.